# Swiftui - Error displaying decoded data to view

Tags: swift, networking, swiftui

Im having trouble displaying data that I have decoded into a struct to my view via environment object that is passed to my view. The error message that shows up is "No exact matches in call to initializer". Iv been trying to figure it out with no luck.

Here is some of my code of my network file that serves as a source of truth for my decoded structs

```
class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var user: LoginResponseData.Root? = nil
    @Published var alert: CustomAlert? = nil
    @Published var claimHistroy: ClaimStruct? = nil
    
    var authentication: AuthenticationCheck? = nil
    
    var showLoader = false
    
    let networkService: NetworkService = NetworkService.shared
    
    func signIn(username: String, password: String) {
        networkService.signIn(username: username, password: password) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let user):
                print("This user last name is: \(user.result.login.userName.name.fullName)")
                self.user = user
                 
                self.authentication?.updateValidation(success: true)
                
                // Calls method
                self.profileSessionMember()
                
            case .failure(let error):
                print("The error is: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                //Reset the variable
                self.user = nil
                self.authentication?.updateValidation(success: false)
                // Pass a message to the user 
                self.alert = CustomAlert(title: "Invalid Credentials", message: "Either username or password is incorrect. Please try again")
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    /// Gets the Search Savings Amouny from decoded struct
    func profileSessionMember() {
        networkService.profileSessionMember { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let userHistory):
                // Sets the claimHistory
                self.claimHistroy = userHistory
                
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            
            }
        }
    }

class AuthenticationCheck: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isValidated = false
    
    func updateValidation(success: Bool) {
        withAnimation {
            isValidated = success
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my authentication where the environmentObject is passed to my view

```
@main
struct SomeApp: App {
    @StateObject var authentication = AuthenticationCheck()
    @StateObject var vm: AuthViewModel = AuthViewModel()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if authentication.isValidated {
                ContentView()
                    .environmentObject(vm)
            } else {
                Signin()
                    .environmentObject(vm)
                    .environmentObject(authentication)

            }
            //TestView()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is where im trying to display the information

```
struct SearchHistory: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: AuthViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("BASED ON YOUR SEARCH HISTORY")
                .font(.title3)
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.584, green: 0.655, blue: 0.992, opacity: 100.0))
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .padding()
            
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "dollarsign.circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 43.0, height: 44.0)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .padding()
                
                VStack{
                    Text("Total")
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    Text("Amount")
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    // This does not work
                    Text(vm.claimHistroy?.result.member.yearToDateSearchSavingsAmount)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In which line appears the error message?

Comment: @Larme the last line in my code that I posted. I have a comment on which code doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text() need to have some string in it to work. Since "vm.claimHistroy" could be nil, try to include some text into it, if it become nil. Something like this:

```
 Text(vm.claimHistroy?.result.member.yearToDateSearchSavingsAmount ?? "")
```

You could even try this:

```
 if let history = vm.claimHistroy {
     Text(history.result.member.yearToDateSearchSavingsAmount)
 }
```

EDIT:

if "yearToDateSearchSavingsAmount" is not a String, try this:

```
if let amount = vm.claimHistroy?.result.member.yearToDateSearchSavingsAmount {
    Text("\(amount)")
}
```

Comment: The first suggestion shows an error that says "Failed to produce diagnostic for expression" please submit a bug report" and displays the same error "No exact matches in call to initializer"

Comment: how about the second suggestion? Does that remove the error?

Comment: is "yearToDateSearchSavingsAmount"  a String?

Comment: I've edited my answer for the case "yearToDateSearchSavingsAmount" is not a String.